# using android application framework classes in client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, android

How do I consume Android Application Framework objects in my client-side JavaScript?

In the Google I/O 2009 Presentation "How Do I Code Thee" http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=GARMe7Km_gk
The speaker discusses this pattern (which he calls augmented JavaScript).

On the Android developer site, I can't seem to find any more information on this pattern or from a search.  Any developers have links they can send on this topic/dev pattern?

Thanks

Comment: See the answer you got below, but note this is only possible from your own application where you provide a `WebView` -- you can't just load in JavaScript and access Android objects from a regular web page accessed via the browser.

Answer (score 1):

[Local access to Java functions from JavaScript on Android](http://www.revis.co.uk/site/node/210)

Comment: Ha, you were beaten by 21 seconds to the identical answer, yet you got the vote! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do it:
http://www.revis.co.uk/site/?q=node/210